# A question about non-symmetric real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a non-symmetric $n\times n$ real matrix. Assume that all eigenvalues of $A$ have positive real parts. Could you please show some simple conditions such that $A+A^T$ is positive definite? Thank you so much.

Comment: The OP's question is very ill-posed. It is well-known that $A+A^T>0$ implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ have positive real part; it's also well-known that the converse is false. The OP clumsily asks for additional conditions on eigenvalues ​​so that $ A + A ^ T $ is positive

Comment: What we want is to find a class of $A$ such that $A+A^T$ is positive.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvector $v$, then $A v = \lambda v$ and $v^{\dagger}A^{\dagger} = \overline{\lambda} v^{\dagger}$ ($\cdot^{\dagger}$ denotes as conjugate transpose, notice that for matrix $A$ it holds $A^T = A^{\dagger}$, because we know that the entries of matrix $A$ are real). Then, by multiplying the first equation by $v^{\dagger}$ from the left and the second equation by $v$ from the right we obtain: 
$$
v^{\dagger} A v = \lambda v^{\dagger} v, \\
v^{\dagger} A^{\dagger} v = \overline{\lambda} v^{\dagger} v.
$$
Hence, $v^{\dagger} (A + A^{\dagger}) v = (\lambda + \overline{\lambda}) v^{\dagger} v = 2\Re(\lambda) \cdot |v| > 0$, if $v \neq 0$. Notice that we worked out this for any pair of eigenvalue-eigenvector $(\lambda, v)$ and since any other vector can be represented by a linear combination of eigenvectors, then this argument remains valid for all $x$, i.e. $x^{\dagger}(A + A^T)x > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$.

So, matrix $A + A^T$ is indeed positive definite without any conditions.

**EDIT**:
As it was noticed by multiple users the conclusion of my answer isn't correct (see comments) and I don't see an obvious solution how to fix this in order to claim that $x^{\dagger}(A + A^T)x > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$. Thanks to @user1551.

Comment: +1 but your answer strictly speaking isn't correct. You have implicitly assumed that $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. As a counterexample to your claim, consider $$A=\pmatrix{1&-1&3&0\\ 1&1&0&3\\ 0&0&1&-1\\ 0&0&1&1}.$$ The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1\pm i$, each of multiplicity $2$, but the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ are $-1,-1,5,5$.

Comment: I think it should be condition that all eigenvectors form the basis

Comment: @user1551 yes, you are right. thanks.

Comment: @Eugene Sirkiza, I think it may do the job. I'll think about it and edit my post shortly, thanks again.

Comment: Oh, wait. The eigenvectors of $A$ are not necessarily mutually orthogonal. Even if they span the whole space, it doesn't immediately follow that $x^\dagger(A+A^T)x>0$ for every $x\ne0$.

Comment: @user1551, yes, I don't find any obvious solution to this issue as well, what should I do with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

As the OP writes, that follows is a class of $A$ s.t. $A+A^T>0$.

Choose $A=[a_{i,j}]$ s.t. for every $i$,

$2a_{i,i}>\sum_{j\not= i}(|a_{i,j}+a_{j,i}|)$;

Comment: Thanks. More precisely, what we want is to find a maximum class of such $A.$

Comment: My friend, if somebody finds an IFF condition, then  he will publish it; he will not offer it to you as a gift.

Comment: Sure, anyway, thanks.